# How to add notification window after pressing "send" button in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I know, that I should import Add-in dll, but I don’t know how to start

Answer (score 0):

Web addin (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) or COM addin (https://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-outlook-addins.php),